# Why is the diagnostic message history not writable as normal user?

Tags: macos, terminal, crash, permission

When I use normally the OS as a plain user I get frequent console messages like:

```
20/05/14 08:21:28,194 SubmitDiagInfo[5376]: Launched to submit Diagnostics and Usage
20/05/14 08:21:28,735 SubmitDiagInfo[5376]: Diagnostic message history store was not writable. Will not submit diagnostic messages.
```

When I give myself admin permissions and boot up I get instead:

```
20/05/14 09:02:44,979 SubmitDiagInfo[432]: SubmitDiagInfo successfully uploaded 2241 diagnostic messages.
```

However when I get back to a normal user I keep getting the former messages, suggesting that disk permissions are somehow broken. Disk Utility doesn't fix them. What magical terminal `chmod` or `chown` incantations should I use to give my plain user access to submit bug reports?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to get those messages? I think the permissions are correct only admin can write using dmeg. This is part of syslog messaging which is flexible so depends on what you are doing

Comment: Nothing special, software which just crashes, for instance, VLC: 20/05/14 09:02:32,583 SubmitDiagInfo[432]: Submitted hang report: file://localhost/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/VLC_2014-04-19-115313_amber.hang``, though that seems separate from the 2241 diagnostic messages sent…